# Creating a class that is an extension of the java.util.HashMap class

Tags: java, superclass

So I'm trying to create an extension of the HashMap class called UniqueHashMap which has all the properties of a the HashMap class, but instead of not being able to have repeated Keys, Values cannot be repeated. If a Value is repeated, the Key gets replaced, eg:

`Apple` -> `Green`

and I try to `put("Pear", "Green")`

we will not have: `Pear` -> `Green`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class UniqueHashMap extends HashMap {

    public UniqueHashMap() {
    }

    public UniqueHashMap(int arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    } 

    public UniqueHashMap(Map arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }

    public UniqueHashMap(int arg0, float arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public V put(K k, V v){
        Set entrySet = (Set) hash.entrySet(); //Store entry of HashMap in a set

        Iterator entryIterator = entrySet.iterator(); //Create iterator for the set

        if(hash.containsValue(v))
        {           
            while(entryIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) entryIterator.next();

                String key = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
                String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

                System.out.println("Key is = " + key + " and Value is = " + value);
                System.out.println();

                if (value.equals(v))
                {
                    hash.remove(key);
                    hash.put(v, value);
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(hash);
        }
    }
```

As you see I have all the constructors of the superclass, however it will not resolve the values that it should inheret from the `HashMap` class (K, V, Hash, Map)

Am I doing the extension wrong? or am I missing some imports?

Comment: Why not just use your values as your keys and vice versa with a regular HashMap?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not an academic task and you just need a collection with unique keys and values - use BiMap.

You can find it in Google Guava ([BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)) and in Apache Commons ([BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html)).

Comment: I can't use the BiMap, have to create the UniqueHashMap class extension. I'm allowed to have repeated Values but not Keys

Answer (score 1):

Since you're performing your unique relation in reverse, your `UniqueHashMap` should delegate to its parent class similarly.

```
 public V put(K k, V v) {
     // reverse the order you put, and what you're keying off of.
     super.put(v, k);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the generic form of `HashMap`, you should do the inheritance this way:

```
public class UniqueHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok, now that I have this, K and V have resolved. However hash (the main Set constructor) has not. Any idea what I can change in the extension?

Comment: but where do you declare the variable `hash`?

Comment: I haven't, I was hoping it would just inheret it from the HashMap class (which it clearly hasn't), however I'm not sure how to declare it, I feel it perhaps should be a Set.

Comment: use `this.entrySet();` instead of `hash.entrySet();`

Comment: Please mark the answer as approved if it solved your problem. An upvote would be also appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap in the other direction where its keys are the first maps values.  I assume this is what Apache Commons' BiMap does.